# What's causing this PermissionError With Multiprocessing Queues?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, queue

I've been exploring queues, pipes, etc. for a project.

The following code was to learn how queues operate:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
def words(liss, q):
    newlis = []
    for i in liss:
        # newlis.append(str(i) + "flag")
        q.put(str(i) + "flag")

def reading(q):
    while not q.empty():
        print(q.get())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = Queue()
    p1 = Process(target=words, args=([23, "Hello", "Hey", 78], q))
    p2 = Process(target=readit, args=(q,))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p1.join()
```

I've tried changing what I put in the queue and running the program with higher permissions. Both ran into this error:

```
Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jonat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 297, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Jonat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 99, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Jonat\PycharmProjects\Giraffe\Small-Tests.py", line 8, in words
    q.put(liss)
  File "C:\Users\Jonat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 82, in put
    if not self._sem.acquire(block, timeout):
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I've found one other post regarding this error, but I didn't quite understand it. Regardless, I'll link the post here: [What is the reason of this errror: "PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54176876/what-is-the-reason-of-this-errror-permissionerror-winerror-5-access-is-deni)

Comment: What is your python version? it seems that issue on python 3.7.2. So rather you can downgrade with 3.7.0 or upgrade to 3.7.4.

Comment: @DipenShah Thanks! That fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by @DipenShah.

This is a known issue with Python 3.7.2
Upgrading or downgrading to a different version should fix it.